# How to upload photo to a server from .net winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a window form application in C#. There is a user registration section where user details are filled and a photo is uploaded. How to upload photo a common location in server not in client system. I need to upload the picture of user to a location in server so that the website section of the application can show the picture in the profile of user.

Comment: Is this website on your intranet or is it somewhere outside on the internet?

Comment: the website is a online version.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually store the information including the picture in the database, so it's available from all your other applications.

if you simply want to copy a raw file from client computer to a centralized location, as a starting point:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    string fileName = textBox1.Text;
    string _path = Application.StartupPath;
    MessageBox.Show(_path);
    _path = _path.Replace("Debug", "Images");
    MessageBox.Show(_path);
    myWebClient.UploadFile(_path,fileName);
}

private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofDlg.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg|GIF|*.gif|PNG|*.png|BMP|*.bmp";
    if (DialogResult.OK == ofDlg.ShowDialog())
    {
        textBox1.Text = ofDlg.FileName;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Go ahead, select a file!");
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i want to store the images to a location in online server like "http//Sitename/Images/uploadedPhoto" not to client system

Answer (score 1):

Maybe best way is to use an FTP Server ,if you can install it .
Than you can upload file's using this code

```
FileInfo toUpload = new FileInfo("FileName");
System.Net.FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://serverip/FileName");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName","Password");
Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
FileStream file = File.OpenRead(files);
int length = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
int bytesRead = 0;
do
{
    bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);
    ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
while (bytesRead != 0);
file.Close();
ftpStream.Close();
```

Comment: how to store file to a non ftp server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 0):

upload a file to FTP server using C# from our local hard disk.

```
private void UploadFileToFTP()
{
   FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.server.com/sample.txt");

   ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
   ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
   ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

   byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\sample.txt");
   ftpReq.ContentLength = b.Length;
   using (Stream s = ftpReq.GetRequestStream())
   {
        s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
   }

   FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();

   if (ftpResp != null)
   {
         if(ftpResp.StatusDescription.StartsWith("226"))
         {
              Console.WriteLine("File Uploaded.");
         }
   }
}
```